# how to extend object types for flow

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I want to be able to extend props A for a component for a wrapper component by adding a few more fields (props C).  When I use a spread operator flow gives an error.

```
type A = {a: string}
type C = {b: number} & A //{b: number, a:string} 
const c : C = {a: 'a', b: 1}
const {b, ...a} = c;
const a2 : A = a;
```

This gives an flow error 
    6: const a2 : A = a;
                  ^ rest of object pattern.

Whats the way around this?

https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeBDAXFAzsATgSwDsBzAXwChRIoBhBZAIwwIFcBbeiHEqAMligD0ApIygt2nADRR02fMW5kyAYwD2BbFGVQMtRKgwByFIemiAjOTUbgDaQDpHKbomUBuFes0oATDv6IKG5AA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the work around to it:

```
type A = {a: string}
type C = {b: number} & A //{b: number, a:string} 

const c : C = {a: 'a', b: 1}
const {b, a} = c;
const a2 : A = {a};
```

Link to : [FLOW](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeBDAXFAzsATgSwDsBzAXwChRIoBhBZAIwwIFcBbeiHEqAMligD0ApIygt2nADRR02fMW5kyAYwD2BbFGVQMtRKgwByFIemiAjOTUbgDaSm6JlAbhXrNKAEw7++h86A)

Comment: Thanks for the workaround.  However it's more verbose if C has ten fields instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

`flow` has a lot of problems with spread operators, [like you can see in the issues](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=spread).
Best workaround at the moment is to explicitly extract each attribute, like Vivek Doshi said.